# How is data store in Hyperledger Fabric when using CouchDB as the Ledger State database?

Tags: couchdb, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm running the code in [Chaincode for Developers Tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html), to run a basic sample chaincode to create assets (key-value pairs) on the ledger.

I'm able to invoke the chaincode using the cli

```
peer chaincode invoke -n mycc -c '{"Args":["set", "a", "20"]}' -C myc
```

and also run queries

```
peer chaincode query -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}' -C myc
```

Now I want to see how the key value pair gets stored in CouchDB. So I changed the environment variables below in the *fabric-samples/chaincode-docker-devmode/docker-compose-simple.yaml*

```
CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
```

I see the documents created like below in CouchDB UI (*http://localhost:5984/myc/_all_docs*) when I run set.

```
{
  "total_rows": 3,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [{
      "id": "lscc\u0000mycc",
      "key": "lscc\u0000mycc",
      "value": {
        "rev": "1-dc6dc8ff92efd35358cf5b89e7949c25"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "mycc\u0000a",
      "key": "mycc\u0000a",
      "value": {
        "rev": "3-7ad1349ec711a99a2a2f1dd1c8b08a20"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "statedb_savepoint",
      "key": "statedb_savepoint",
      "value": {
        "rev": "6-2c3d131fc75772cc9e70311998bdde9d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How/Where is the value for the key stored and retrieved? It is seen as below, when checking the document in the DB, but is retrieved properly when running the chaincode get query.

```
"value": {
  "rev": "3-7ad1349ec711a99a2a2f1dd1c8b08a20"
}
```

When

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While key persisted into DB it is prefixed with name of the chaincode, in your example it's `mycc` and as a separator used `[]byte{0x00}` value. Therefore you see in you example, following output:

```
{
  "id": "mycc\u0000a",
  "key": "mycc\u0000a",
  "value": {
    "rev": "3-7ad1349ec711a99a2a2f1dd1c8b08a20"
  }
},
```

which stands for key `a` of chaincode `mycc`. To get the value of this key you can simply run a `curl` command as following adding query parameter `attachements=true`, for example:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5984/mychannel/mycc%00a?attachments=true"
```

will result with something similar to this:

```
--bdb0a91d2e233fdc193f2359e6a50472
Content-Type: application/json

{"_id":"mycc\u0000a","_rev":"2-2af72e502c2b43c73064728852103fbf","chaincodeid":"mycc","version":"4:0","_attachments":{"valueBytes":{"content_type":"application/octet-stream","revpos":2,"digest":"md5-qpvq4/JGMCgu7WtvFu5zbg==","length":2,"follows":true,"encoding":"gzip","encoded_length":22}}}
--bdb0a91d2e233fdc193f2359e6a50472
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="valueBytes"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 22
Content-Encoding: gzip

4鯄i
--bdb0a91d2e233fdc193f2359e6a50472--%
```

For more information about how to read data from CouchDB you might find following [tutorial](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html) useful.

Comment: http://localhost:5984/myc/_all_docs give the following output

{
  "total_rows": 3,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [{
      "id": "lscc\u0000mycc",
      "key": "lscc\u0000mycc",
      "value": {
        "rev": "1-35f379c3ea35ef0077b595923bf36151"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "mycc\u0000a",
      "key": "mycc\u0000a",
      "value": {
        "rev": "2-f3049e0b19f6969f01671889c8b1456f"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "statedb_savepoint",
      "key": "statedb_savepoint",
      "value": {
        "rev": "3-62ba0d88e905ef321c85c542bec7bd15"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: How do I get the value of the key 'mycc\u0000a' ? http://localhost:5984/myc/mycc\u0000a doesn't seem to work. Tried URL encoded http://localhost:5984/myc/mycc%5Cu0000a also

Comment: How is it converted to '/mycc%00a', which seems to be working curl -X GET "http://localhos":5984/myc/mycc%00a?attachments=true".

Comment: I guess the question was how to query the world state of *a* - should be now something affected by invocing *a* with *20*

Answer (score 2):

Since the data is saved in binary, you won’t find exact values(instead you will find hashes) but will see the records having key containing *mycc*

Comment: single-line solution/suggestion should be posted in comment.

Comment: Sure Rumit. Since I didn't had enough reputation, I just answered. Thank you